# Is overloading the correct way to accept string or List<string> as an argument?

Tags: c#, function

I have a function which takes as argument a list of `string`.

Most of the calls will only use a single string, and therefore, I would like to be able to pass a `string`, instead of a `List<string>`, to make things easier.

I have implemented this with an overload:

```
public object foo(string bar)
{
    return foo(new List<string> { bar });
}

public object foo(List<string> bar)
{
    //Some Code
}
```

Is this the correct way to implement this, or is there a easier / best practice way of achieving this?

Comment: It depends on what the method is doing.. If most of the calls are with a `string` what are the cases when it is a `List<string>` and what do you do then? With no details it looks good (no code repetition) but for a serious answer we need to know more

Comment: For correct ways etc. I think you need to be at [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/) or [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) as this already works (no error)

Comment: This is one of the reasons for overloading existance. It's fine.

Comment: @EpicKip this would be closed on CR as example code.

Comment: Based on provided information it is nice and maintainable approach, you can even change single string to be a `params string[] bar`, and then `return foo(bar.ToList());`.

Comment: @Heslacher It should technically be closed here so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you have is fine. This is what operator overloading is for.

FWIW, if most of the calls will only use a single string, I'd go the other way, if possible. Also I'd use the most general interface that does the job.

```
public object foo(string bar)
{
    //Some code
}

public object foo(IEnumerable<string> bar)
{
    foreach (var s in bar) foo(s);
}
```

Or possibly:

```
public object foo(string bar)
{
    //Some code
}

public IEnumerable<object> foo(IEnumerable<string> bar)
{
    return bar.Select(a => foo(a));
}
```

But let's say reversing the wrap order is a bad idea (as some commenters have suggested). Here's a fun way to avoid writing a second prototype: add a helper extension method.

```
//Helper extension method
public static IEnumerable<T> ToEnumerable<T>(this T item)
{
    yield return item; 
}


//Then just have one prototype
public object foo(List<bar>)
{
    //some code
}

//But call it like this if you want
var result = foo(bar.ToEnumerable());
```

But if you'd rather just have two prototypes, that is totes on fleek too.

Comment: You are not considering the return value. What if the return value is determined by the action on the whole bunch of strings?

Comment: This approach will work only in the specific case you used, sadly OP didn't provide more information. For example if method accepted list save all data to the database, then with your approach saving one item at the time will not be better approach anymore

Answer (score 1):

What about `params`?

```
public object foo(params string[] bar)
{
    //impl
}
```

you can call it like this: `foo("abc")` or like this: `foo(new []{"abc","xyz"})`